# How to assign an div id a variable without using Javascript?

Tags: html, jsp

I'm trying to create multiple divs inside a for loop on a jsp page. I'm loading all the posts in a forum from a database, each one being a new div. I'm trying to make divs having id like `id= "post-" + title`, where `title` is a variable.

I tried with this way of puting `out.printlnt(title)` and is not working, I also found a solution saying to put smth like `div id = {{title}}` that still didn't work. Do you know if is possible to do this without using javascript? I just want to assign the id from the for loop.

```
for (ForumPost fp : allForumPosts) {
//get title and likes variables
<div id = "<%out.println(title);%>" >
<%out.println(title); out.println(likes);%>
<a>LIKE</a>
</div>
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `<%= ... %>`?

Comment: You should use `<%out.print(...);%>` instead of `<%out.println(..);%>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using jstl (which is preferred way to scriptlets) you can do this the following way:

```
<c:forEach var="post" items="${allForumPosts}">
    <div id="post-${post.title}">
        ${post.title}; ${post.likes} <a>LIKE</a>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Just make sure to include this tag at the top of your jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

If you want to use scriptlets as you do now, I think you should do something like:

```
<% for (ForumPost fp : allForumPosts) {%>
    <div id="post-<%out.write(fp.title)%>">
        <%out.write(fp.title)%>;<%out.write(fp.likes)%>
        <a>LIKE</a>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

But you **really** should consider using jstl instead of scriptlets

Answer (score 1):

[Java Server Pages (JSP)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/) is a server-side programming technology for your front-end.

Assuming that you have passed the object from your controller to JSP, then you can achieve the desired for loop with [JSTL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:forEach items="${allForumPosts}" var="post">
    <div id="post-${post.title}"></div>
</c:forEach>
```

If you however prefer *scriptlet* (not recommended), here is how it's done

```
<% for (ForumPost post : allForumPosts) { %>
    <div id="post-<%=post.title%>"></div>
<% } %>
```